# Issues pinging computer on network

Tags: networking, ping

I am having a problem pinging a particular computer on my network. We use the same Subnet and use static IP addresses. I cannot ping this computer from any other computer but I can ping out from that computer. Example: A can't ping B but B can ping A.

I am not all that savy in networking. What could be causing this? The computer is on our domain and has correct GP. also checked and IPV6 is unchecked.

Comment: The firewall...

Comment: What would make the firewall do this suddenly? This computer is not a new computer and has been fine until just recently.

Comment: Are you using a security software (norton, mcaffe, etc.)? Perhaps it got updated or had its configuration changed which caused the firewall to block pings.

Comment: You should not disable IPv6, that's not the problem. If anything it can only help since `ping -v6 remoteMachine` could still work even if "remoteMachine" had no IPv4 address. Regardless, it does sound like the Windows Firewall changed profiles and started blocking ICMP (ping requests).

Comment: You say it's been fine until recently. Does that mean you randomly ping the devices or has something else stopped working causing you to try pinging?

Comment: ...also unless the domain's Group Policy explicitly allows inbound PING on _all_ 3 Windows Firewall rules, then it would not prevent this.

Comment: we are using mcafee endpoint security which is pushed via GP to all computers on domain. We do ping some machines at random times for various reasons, sometimes to shutdown the machine if the workers arent doing it at night which they are notorious for on that particular machine. The reason we were trying to ping this time was because we were trying to get into the services remotely and couldnt so we pinged it to make sure it was turned on and thats when we discovered the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a constant ping to the machine in question like so:
`ping -t remoteMachineName`

...then, just as a temporary measure to troubleshoot, disable the Windows Firewall **completely** (all 3 profiles). If that resolves the issue you should re-enable the 3 Firewall profiles on the affect machine, issue this command (run as admin) to set the proper firewall rules:
`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="allow IPv4 ping" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow`

Windows 10 uses a service called NLA (network location awareness) to essentially "guess" which Firewall profile to use (Private, Domain/Work, Public) and if/when it guesses incorrectly it blocks inbound PING requests.